# Show frequencies along with barplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, frequency

I'm trying to display frequencies within barplot ... well, I want them **somewhere** in the graph: under the bars, within bars, above bars or in the legend area. And I recall (I may be wrong) that it can be done in `ggplot2`. This is probably an easy one... at least it seems easy. Here's the code:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars)
p + aes(factor(cyl)) + geom_bar()
```

Is there any chance that I can get frequencies embedded in the graph?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`geom_text` is tha analog of `text` from base graphics:

```
p + geom_bar() + stat_bin(aes(label=..count..), vjust=0, 
                          geom="text", position="identity")
```

If you want to adjust the y-position of the labels, you can use the `y=` aesthetic within `stat_bin`: for example, `y=..count..+1` will put the label one unit above the bar.

The above also works if you use `geom_text` and `stat="bin"` inside.

Comment: For the label, why is there a ".." preceding and following the count?

Comment: `..count..` is the name of the variable containing the bin frequencies that `stat_bin` creates automatically. So the two periods before and after it are part of the variable name

Comment: This answer gave an error for me `Error: stat_count requires the following missing aesthetics: x`.  However, adding in the `aes(factor(cyl))` and changing `stat_bin` to `stat_count` as in `p + aes(factor(cyl)) + geom_bar() + stat_count(aes(label=..count..), vjust=0, geom="text", position="identity")` did work.

Comment: for me `+ geom_text(aes(label=..count..), stat="count")` worked (instead of `stat="bin"`)

Answer (score 4):

A hard way to do it. I'm sure there are better approaches.

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(factor(cyl))) + 
geom_bar() + 
geom_text(aes(y=sapply(cyl,function(x) 1+table(cyl)[names(table(cyl))==x]),
label=sapply(cyl,function(x) table(cyl)[names(table(cyl))==x])))
```

Comment: It's generally good practice to create your data _outside_ of your plotting code.  And it is _never_ a good idea to shove data into the aesthetic mappings.

Answer (score 1):

When wanting to add different info the following works:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=clusterSize, y=occurence)) +
geom_bar() + geom_text(aes(x=clusterSize, y=occurence, label = mydata$otherinfo))
```

Comment: Can you, please, replicate this answer by providing an example that refers to data available in `datasets` package (or other package available in CRAN repos)? I doubt that barplot can be drawn with `y` variable specified "as is"...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, I found useful to use some of the available annotation functions: `ggplot2::annotate`, `ggplot2::annotation_custom` or `cowplot::draw_label` (which is a wrapper of `annotation_custom`).

`ggplot2::annotate` is just recycling the geom text option. More advantageous for plotting anywhere on the canvas are the possibilities offered by `ggplot2::annotation_custom` or `cowplot::draw_label`.

## Examples with `ggplot2::annotate`

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars) + aes(factor(cyl)) + geom_bar()

# Get data from the graph
p_dt <- layer_data(p) # or ggplot_build(p)$data

p + annotate(geom = "text", label = p_dt$count, x = p_dt$x, y = 15)
```

[image]

Or allow `y` to vary:

```r
p + annotate(geom = "text", label = p_dt$count, x = p_dt$x, y = p_dt$y + 1)
```

[image]

## Example with `ggplot2::annotation_custom`

The `ggplot2::annotate` has limitations when trying to plot in more "unconventional" places, as it was asked originally ("**somewhere** in the graph"). However, `ggplot2::annotation_custom` in combination with [setting clipping off](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/2539), allows annotation **anywhere** on the canvas/sheet, as the below example shows:

```r
p2 <- p + coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
for (i in 1:nrow(p_dt)){
  p2 <- p2 + annotation_custom(grid::textGrob(p_dt$count[i]), 
                               xmin = p_dt$x[i], xmax = p_dt$x[i], ymin = -1, ymax = -1)
}
p2
```

[image]

## Example with `cowplot::draw_label`

`cowplot::draw_label` is a wrapper of `ggplot2::annotation_custom`, and is slightly less verbose (as a consequence). It also needs clipping off to plot anywhere on the canvas.

```r
library(cowplot)
#> Warning: package 'cowplot' was built under R version 3.5.2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'cowplot'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     ggsave
# Revert to default theme; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41096936/5193830
theme_set(theme_grey())

p3 <- p + coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
for (i in 1:nrow(p_dt)){
  p3 <- p3 + draw_label(label = p_dt$count[i], x = p_dt$x[i], y = -1.8)
}
p3
```

[image]

Note that, `draw_label` can also be used in combination with `cowplot::ggdraw`, switching to relative coordinates, ranging from 0 to 1 (relative to the entire canvas, see examples with `help(draw_label)`). In that case setting `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")` is not required anymore as things are taken care by `ggdraw`.

<sup>Created on 2019-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

If you are not restricted to ggplot2, you could use ?text from base graphics or ?boxed.labels from the plotrix package.