# How to add count labels in ggplot2 barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, label, geom-text

I'm trying to place count labels in a ggplot2 barplot and I haven't been able to do it. I need to display the number of pixels within each temperature range.
The dataframe was built from a raster: EneroT5cmSC

```
datene <- as.data.frame(EneroT5cmSC,xy=TRUE)%>%drop_na()
datene$cuts <- cut(datene$layer, breaks=seq(21, 29, length.out=12))
```

dput:

```
datene_stuc <-  structure(
list(
  x = c(-57.063098328,-57.021448328,-56.996458328,-56.988128328),
  y = c(-30.087481664,-30.087481664,-30.087481664,-30.087481664),
  layer = c(
    25.6227328470624,
    26.6386584334308,
    26.0636709134397,
    26.0580615984563
  ),
  cuts = structure(
    c(7L, 9L,
      8L, 8L),
    .Label = c(
      "(20,20.8]",
      "(20.8,21.6]",
      "(21.6,22.5]",
      "(22.5,23.3]",
      "(23.3,24.1]",
      "(24.1,24.9]",
      "(24.9,25.7]",
      "(25.7,26.5]",
      "(26.5,27.4]",
      "(27.4,28.2]",
      "(28.2,29]"
    ),
    class = "factor"
  )
),
row.names = c(NA,
              4L),
class = "data.frame")
```

Barplot code:

```
ggplot() +
geom_bar(data = datene, aes(cuts, fill = cuts)) + 
scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "B",'Temp (Cº)') +
theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
geom_text(aes(label = ..count..), stat = "count", vjust = 1.5, colour = "black")
```

[image: The labels on each bar do not appear]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show frequencies along with barplot in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551921/show-frequencies-along-with-barplot-in-ggplot2)

Comment: I replace: geom_text(aes(label = ..count..), stat = "count", vjust = 1.5, colour = "black") for stat_bin(aes(label=..count..), vjust=0, geom="text", position="identity") and sadly continued with the same result. Labels don't appear. Thanks Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the code arguments from `geom_bar` to `ggplot()` and change `vjust = -1` it works like this:

```r
datene_stuc <-  structure(
  list(
    x = c(-57.063098328,-57.021448328,-56.996458328,-56.988128328),
    y = c(-30.087481664,-30.087481664,-30.087481664,-30.087481664),
    layer = c(
      25.6227328470624,
      26.6386584334308,
      26.0636709134397,
      26.0580615984563
    ),
    cuts = structure(
      c(7L, 9L,
        8L, 8L),
      .Label = c(
        "(20,20.8]",
        "(20.8,21.6]",
        "(21.6,22.5]",
        "(22.5,23.3]",
        "(23.3,24.1]",
        "(24.1,24.9]",
        "(24.9,25.7]",
        "(25.7,26.5]",
        "(26.5,27.4]",
        "(27.4,28.2]",
        "(28.2,29]"
      ),
      class = "factor"
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,
                4L),
  class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = datene_stuc, aes(cuts, fill = cuts)) +
  geom_bar() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = ..count..), stat = "count", vjust = -1, colour = "black") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "B",'Temp (Cº)') +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>